# C++: Variables change values after initialization of different class

Tags: c++, variables, memory, initialization, member

I have the following problem.

```
PerspectiveCamera pcam2(Point(0, 0, 0), Vector(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f), Vector(0, 0, 1), pi * 0.9f, pi * 0.9f);
Renderer r12(&pcam2,0);
```

In the above code, `pcam2` is initialized and then after that, `&pcam2` is passed on to `r12`.

`pcam2` has members `const Point& center`, `const Vector& forward`, `const Vector& up`, and two `float` numbers that are passed upon initialization in said order.

`r12` has members `Camera* cam_` and an `int` number.

The strange thing that happens is that during the initialization of `r12`, the values of the field `center` of `pcam2` get changed to some bogus like `Point(1.984192e+27, 4.59149455e-41, 0)` when in the code you can see that `pcam2` was initialized with `Point(0, 0, 0)`.
Literally all that happens during initialization of `r12` is that its members are assigned their values via member initialization list.

I really don't understand what is happening here and I don't know enough about C++ to find out on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem (at least one of them) is that you're storing references to objects that no longer exist when you get to using them. Don't use references as members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Point(0, 0, 0)` is a temporary object which lives only until the nearest `;`. If you store a reference to it inside `pcam2`, this reference becomes dangling right after the line with `pcam2` initialization is complete. Any access to the dangling reference afterwards is undefined behavior.

You typically don't need to store any references in `struct`s, having ownership semantics (i.e. storing by-value and copying/moving data into `struct`) is less errorprone and easier to reason about.

Comment: Is there any way to extend the lifetime of my temporary object while still passing it by reference?

Comment: @JaneCherrytree That's approaching the problem from the wrong angle – if you don't use references as members, the problem will disappear.

Comment: The issue is that this framework was provided to me with the members of the classes as const references, I'm assuming for performance reasons, so I would really like to solve this as intended. I now understand why passing by value would solve this problem, I'm just trying to understand the framework.

Comment: @JaneCherrytree No, there is no way to extend lifetime of a temporary (other than the obscure lifetime extension rule which works for a single level of local const references). You can create a value which outlives `pcam2`, though. For example, a struct which contains all necessary fields and `pcam2` which references to the fields. You have to make sure that this struct is non-movable, though. This is exteremely strange behavior on framework's behalf, though.

Comment: SO to be very clear, constructing a class with ```const &``` members and then calling the constructor of this class with temporary objects as parameters is wrong? So there is nothing I can do except change the class so that it takes values instead of ```const``` references?

Comment: @JaneCherrytree If these temporary objects are stored to `const &` members - yes, exactly. You can either change the class or pass non-temporary values instead (but you have to look out for their lifetime).